# Web page authentication and sessions

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, http-headers, access-token

I'm trying to understand how most online websites authenticate and then store your session. What I'm particularly trying to understand is when I log into a website it starts off by redirecting me to the login page and then validates my username/password, then navigates back to where I started but with my information displayed. If I were to navigate away from that webpage and then come back to it sometime later I'm still logged in. I feel like this is what a cookie could be used for but I'm looking to see if anyone could provide me with a good explanation as to how this works?

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what cookies do.  Learn about cookies.

Comment: Give [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) a read and show us what you can come up with, then we'll gladly assist you.

Answer (score 1):

A cookie is a bit of data stored by the browser and sent to the server with every request for instance a subscription status on a website.

A session is a collection of data stored on the server and associated with a given user (usually via a cookie containing an id code)

Session values are reset after the connection is closed. Cookies values are normally saved.
Session values are usually reset after a period of time has passed without a connection from the client with which the session is associated. Cookie values are saved until their expiry time (or the browser is closed if one isn't set). Expire immediately overrides are available for both